# The friendliest of both brothers

Tags: grammar

Which is the most correct?

Jean is the friendliest of both brothers

or

Jean is the friendlier of both sisters.

Answer (score 5):

Neither of the two sentences:

> - (1) Jean is the friendliest of both brothers.
> - (2) Jean is the friendlier of both sisters.

is really good, natural English.

The first issue is that the superlative "*friendliest*" is not used unless there are three or more choices. (I recall a line in a novel that a woman saying "My dearest husband" implied (incorrectly) that she had at least three husbands.) this issue occurs only in sentence (1).

The second issue is that "*both*" is not used in that sort of construction. a more natural version would be:

> (2A) Jean is the friendlier of the two sisters.

this would work just as well with "brothers" or any other noun indicating a group of people, for example "friends".

Answer (score 0):

By the way, Jean is female in English. Jean is only male in French.

The problem is the word "both". It doesn't belong here.

> Jean is the friendliest of the brothers
> Jean is the friendlier of the
> sisters.

I think "the friendlier" is mostly used where there are two, and "the friendliest" where there are more than two.